# Javascript: Validation alerts 2

Tags: javascript, email, alert, verification

My goal is this:

1. Check if `email` and `name` are empty. If so, give 'Enter email or name' alert.
2. If they do, check for an @ in `email` If none is found, give 'Bad email' alert.
3. Check if `email` and `name` contain any letters, if they do, give 'Success' alert

   ```
   function test(email, name){

   if(email=="" || name == "") {
       alert("Enter mail or name");}
       return false;

   if(email.indexOf("@") == -1){
       alert("Bad email");}
       return false;

   var a = email.length;
   var b = name.length;

   if(a==>0, b==>0){
       alert("Message sent");}
       return true;
   }
   ```

This is what I've come up with so far, but it isn't working. I'm quite new at javascript so maybe you guys could tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: Define "isn't working". What happens instead of what you expect to happen? Also you have some VERY funky indentation here. Try running your code through http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Take a look at the location of your ending curly brackets for you `if` statements.

Comment: Here's what your code looks like with proper indentation. https://gist.github.com/Squeegy/8246604  From here the problem should be pretty apparent :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is the close bracket is in the wrong place.  You have it at the end of your alert statement and you probably want the return to be included with your if statement.  if this is the case then change it to be:

```
 function test(email, name){

        if(email=="" || name == "") {
            alert("Enter mail or name");
            return false;
        }

        if(email.indexOf("@") == -1){
            alert("Bad email");
            return false;
        }

        var a = email.length;
        var b = name.length;

        if(a > 0 && b > 0){
            alert("Message sent");
            return true;
        }
}
```

A better way to do the same thing would be because that way you're not checking the variables for length and size twice:

```
function test(email, name) {
   var a = email.length;
   var b = name.length;

   if ( a > 0  && b > 0 ) {
      // ignore 0 because email addresses shouldn't start with @
      if ( email.indexOf("@") > 0 ) {
         alert("Message sent");
         return true;
      }
      else {
        alert("Bad email");
        return false;
      }
   }
   else {
      alert("Enter mail or name");
      return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this JSFiddle that seems to fit your needs http://jsfiddle.net/9nF5W/

```
function test(email, name) {

    if (email == "" || name == "") {
        alert("Enter mail or name");
        return false;
    }

    if (email.indexOf("@") == -1) {
        alert("Bad email");
        return false;
    }

    var a = email.length;
    var b = name.length;

    if (a > 0 && b > 0) {
        alert("Message sent");
    }
    return true;
}

test('tes@t', 'test');
```

I think there is an other mistake than the returns statements in "`if(a==>0, b==>0){`" by the way.